# Pass a lamda expression in a thread pool

Tags: multithreading, c++11, pool

I try yo compile in C++11 the following piece of code without success. My goal is to use lambda expression instead of bind in order to fill a queue with tasks.
Could you please help me?
Is any case to create a dangling reference ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
std::queue<std::function<void()>> funcs;
class A
{
public:
    void foo(int a )
    {
        cout << "Hello word" << endl;
    }
};
class ThePool
{
 public:
 template<typename _Callable, typename Object, typename... _Args>
 void QueueFunction(_Callable __f, Object  obj, _Args... __args)
 { 
       funcs.push([=]()
                {
                     (obj.*__f)((__args...));
                });          
    }
    void print(int i )
    {
       cout << "Hello Word"<< i <<endl;
    }
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
ThePool t;
A a ;
t.QueueFunction(&A::foo,a,5);
std::function<void()> func = funcs.back();
func();
return 0;
}
```

The error that is generated is the following

> main.cpp:24:38: error:
>   parameter packs not expanded with '...':
>                             (obj.*__f)((__args...));
>                                         ^ main.cpp:24:38: note:         '__args' main.cpp:24:44: error: expected ')' before '...' token
>                             (obj.*__f)((__args...));
>                                               ^ main.cpp:24:49: error: expected ')' before ';' token
>                             (obj.*__f)((__args...));
>                                                    ^ main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)': main.cpp:39:45: error: conversion
>   from 'std::function' to non-scalar type
>   'std::function' requested
>        std::function func = funcs.back();
>                                                ^ main.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct ThePool::QueueFunction(_Callable, Object,
>   _Args ...) [with _Callable = void (A::*)(int); Object = A; _Args = {int}]::__lambda0': main.cpp:22:12:   required from 'void
>   ThePool::QueueFunction(_Callable, Object, _Args ...) [with _Callable =
>   void (A::*)(int); Object = A; _Args = {int}]' main.cpp:38:32:
>   required from here main.cpp:24:38: error: using invalid field
>   'ThePool::QueueFunction(_Callable, Object, _Args
>   ...)::__lambda0::____args'
>                             (obj.*__f)((__args...));

Comment: Too late for me to check. Could it be the extra brackets in ((__args...)) ?

Comment: Two problems. First, an extra pair of parens around `__args`: make it `(obj.*__f)(__args...)`. Second, you capture `obj` by value, so it's copied into a member of the lambda. Lambda is const by default, and so are all its members. But you are trying to call a non-const member function on that copy. You can make the lambda mutable: `funcs.push([=]() mutable { ... });` With these two changes, [your example compiles](http://rextester.com/TPFPC72558)

Comment: Note however that names starting with underscore followed by capital letter, and those containing two underscores, are reserved for implementation. So technically, your program exhibits undefined behavior for that reason.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you for the comments. It compiles. To copy the object I think that is necessary in order to avoid dangling reference. Is this right? Ι suppose that this has also affect when the bind is used. The class object should be passed by value in order to be copied. If  I am not right please correct me.